# Clustering several instances of Apache Zeppelin?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I have been testing Apache Zeppelin to query several sources hosted on Apache Drill and then creating charts to analyze our data.
Since the product seems robust enough, I have been planning on rolling our analyst team over this solution for monitoring and discovering business data.

The problem I face now is that only 1 instance of Zeppelin will not be enough to manage concurrently the users (and thinking about HA, it's not a good idea on relying exclusively on 1 host). I have already built an Apache Drill cluster to be able to handle the traffic volumes, but I couldn't find anything on the documentation on how to build a cluster of several Zeppelin instances to share their notebooks and user sessions behind a load balancer.

Can you advice if what I'm trying to do is posible? If so, can you point me on the right direction?

Thanks

EDIT: Been playing with Zeppelin 0.8.0-snapshot and MongoDB integration to store notebooks. Although it seems to be able to write new and update notebooks, other connected Zeppelin instances will only update their internal notebooks after a restart.

Comment: You can share notebooks between Zeppelin instances via additional notebook storage such as mongo as you mentioned. But you can't share sessions among multiple Zeppelin instances. Because it's persisted in memory not 3rd part storage like redis. Thus I don't think we are able to set up fully configured HA Zeppelin instances in current version (0.8-SNAPSHOT)

Comment: It would be nice to report an issue in JIRA if mongo notebook storage has a bug. (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN)

Comment: The only problem I am facing is that, once the zeppelin instance read the notebooks from MongoDB into internal memory, it will never update its internal notebook states from MongoDB during its lifetime, although It will write any updates to it. If you think this might be considered as a bug, I will gladly open a ticket.

Comment: I am not sure that is bug or intended. The only thing i can say is, it's unsafe implementation. If zeppelin is down exceptionally, the notebooks persisted in memory will be lost. IMO, it's good to open a ticket.

Comment: Write and done through the MongoDB, so they won't be lost, I can assure you that, I have tested it. The missing part is, when accessing a new notebook, to trigger a "loadAll" from MongoDB. Although there are still some issue over concurrency writes.